# Error in Dynamic SOQL when binding a variable

Tags: soql, batch, dynamic-soql

I have a batch apex that contains a constructor, but when I tried to run it, I'm receiving an error saying variable does not exist fromDate, is there something I need to do to correct the query?

thank you for answering my question

public Constructor(objName, fromDate, toDate){
query = 'SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate FROM '+objName+' WHERE CreatedDate >= :fromDate AND CreatedDate <= :toDate';
}

Comment: This code cannot compile. Please edit your question to include actual code that can compile, as well as the exact error message and things you've tried to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your class is like this:

```java
public inherited sharing class MyFirstBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    String query;
    
    public MyFirstBatch(objName, fromDate, toDate) {
        // Here lies the issue: fromDate and toDate exist only here
        query = 'SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate FROM '+objName+' WHERE CreatedDate >= :fromDate AND CreatedDate <= :toDate';
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // fromDate and toDate are not defined here so you got that error
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> scope) {
        // do something
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // something else
    }
}
```

`fromDate` and `toDate` are local variables. This means that they exist only in the constructor, so in `start` method, when the string is used and *resolved* to execute the query, they are not defined. That's why you got that error.

You should define `objName`, `fromDate` and `toDate` as instance variables, then build the query string in the `start` method:

```java
String objName;
String fromDate
String toDate;
    
public MyFirstBatch(objName, fromDate, toDate) {
    this.objName = objName;
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
    this.toDate = toDate;
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate FROM '+objName+' WHERE CreatedDate >= :fromDate AND CreatedDate <= :toDate');
}
```